# Some use cases of Seeds in DBT (Data built tool)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Suppose we have a CSV file in DBT with fields like I'd and First_name but name is in Lower case ...
While loading the data covert it to upper case without using any extra space or creating macros for the same .

Comment: I'm not sure if DBT is doing that or just passing it to Snowflake as-is. Snowflake will uppercase any lowercase object names unless wrapped in `"double_quotes"`. Be forewarned, it's fighting the natural syntax in Snowflake. You'll be typing double quotes forever.

Comment: It's not about just the column name I want to covert records in upper case in dbt. For eg . I have a csv file with 2  columns I'd and first_name with 100 records and now I want to convert the lower case first_name records to upper case .

Comment: Can you provide a sample of input data (with any personal data anonymized) and a table showing the intended output? As far as converting lowercase names to uppercase, that's just usage of the `upper` function. There may be more to it, so sample input and output will be very helpful.

Comment: Suppose we have a csv file name details.csv which contains records like ID and name . Fir e.g. 1001 beck , 1002 nick, 1003 jack.... but while loading this file from seeds folder I want to change records to upper case like 1001 BECK, 1002 NICK, 1003 JACK...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `quote_columns` config for seeds. From [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/quote_columns):

> An optional seed configuration, used to determine whether column names in the seed file should be quoted when the table is created.

The default is to **not** quote on Snowflake; Snowflake then converts your field names to `SHOUT_CASE`. If you set `quote_columns=True` (see the docs on how to do this for your specific seed or all seeds), Snowflake will respect the case of the quoted name that gets passed to it.